# Show data immediately when listView update

Tags: android

I create a simple database , i can write and read successfully.

Now i want to show it immediately on screen when i write the data down.

I try to use Thread and call `thread.start();` it's not working

What step do i miss ? any help will be gratefully.

here is my thread code in listView , it's under main onCreate

```
Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sqlForBloodSugar = new MySqlForBloodSugar(BloodSugarReportActivity.this, "bloodSugar.db", null, 1);

            Cursor cursor = sqlForBloodSugar.getReadableDatabase().query("blood", null, null, null, null, null, null);

            SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    BloodSugarReportActivity.this,
                    R.layout.blood_sugar_report_list_item_layout,
                    cursor,
                    new String[]{"_id", "bloodvalue", "eattime", "blooddate"},
                    new int[]{R.id.item_id, R.id.item_bloodSugar, R.id.item_eatTime, R.id.item_date},
                    0);

            listViewBloodReport.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
            simpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem updating UI elements from other thread.
If exists some error messages let us know.

For updating UI elements from other thread , you must use **runOnUiThread**.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                //Do something on UiThread
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks , i try your code , it still can't show the data changing immediately . There's no error message.
The just add successfully like my code.

Comment: what you mean when saying **immediately** ?

Comment: use debugging and look where is data loosed

Comment: I mean when i click a button for adding data, the data will show it on the screen at the same time.